# Generar informe agregando imagenes

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una google sheet. Tiene varios campos, casi todos de texto. Unos de los campos tiene un link directo de una imagen.  Necesito crear un informe que me formatee la información y agregue la imagen del enlace.

Comment: Hola xcube, bienvenido a [es.so] te recomiendo hacer el [tour] para entender el funcionamiento del sitio y ganar tu primera medalla! Además considera visitar [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Te puede servir la función [IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333)

Si tenés funciones en castellano, supongo que es IMAGEN(...).

Comment: se te agradece la intención pero es mejor no suponer y colocar una respuesta completa y objetiva, deacuerdo a la info, que provea el OP; ahora si le hace falta datos entonces déjaselo saber en un comentario